# Fortran and OpenMP: Why are OpenMP directives not allowed inside pure procedures?

Tags: fortran, openmp, procedure

I currently use OpenMP to parallelize a legacy application. During my work we added INTENTs to parameters of subroutines and functions which are meant to be called in parallel threads and used extensively the keywork pure to get the compiler to check for side-effect free code for functions and subroutinges to be sure not to change any global state.

Now it came to my attention, that within the OpenMP standard (including the 4.0 draft) it is written:

> "Fortran Restrictions: The following restriction applies to all OpenMP
>   directives: • OpenMP directives may not appear in PURE or ELEMENTAL
>   procedures."

Why is that so? Especially INTENT and pure are great tools to force the compiler to check for side-effect-free code. Why is it not allowed to be combined? What is the technical reason behind it?

The currently implemented code compiles and runs bug free, without any complains and it is really running in parallel, as we can see it with tools and the process management tools.

If it is not working that way, how can we utilize the compiler to check for side-effect-free code and run it in parallel with OpenMP? The current application make extensive use of (changed) global state for runtime control which we need to identify.

It was tested mostly with Intel Fortran Compiler (ifort).

Comment: For clarity consider editing the question title - "Why are OpenMP directives not allowed inside pure procedures?" as you are allowed (more typically, required!) to do the converse.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right.

Comment: @Rick-RainerLudwig - I took the liberty of changing the [tag:pure] tag on this question, because the [tag:pure] tag is really incohesive, referring to [pure](http://beebole.com/pure/) and [pure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_(programming_language)) and "pure CSS" as well as pure procedures in Fortran. I don't know Fortran, so if my edit makes no sense, please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

OpenMP does things that are really not simple, like launching threads and interacting with the operating system. This is not very compatible with the conceptual model of pure procedures.

Comment: Yes, that's for sure, but the OpenMP implementation should be transparent for Fortran itself. Fortran can assure, that a subroutine/function is pure and has not site-effects. What OpenMP makes out of this later on is not relevant at this time, but the Fortran code itself is site-effect-free which is an important condition for parallel execution. So what is wrong in my thinking?

Comment: It is side-effect free until there is some runtime exception in the threading library. Remember even `write`, `stop` and `error stop` are not allowed in pure procedures.

Comment: Yes, that's clear, but I do not see the real problem here. Pure is for Fortran and I want the Fortran code which is to be run in parallel site-effect-free. After applying OpenMP it is not pure anymore, that's ok. And I do not have an issue with that. The parallel execution for the algorithms should be safe due to the pure checks. But, what is now the reason not to use OpenMP in pure functions? What can be broken really? What is the issue? There must be a technical reason to warn for the usage in pure procedures. What is it?

Comment: PURE makes guarantees to the caller of the procedure about how global machine state will be altered.  The behaviour of OpenMP directives depends on the order of execution of those directives in a way that breaks those guarantees.

Comment: I thought about this explanation, but forall and where are allowed also, so it is not just the order of computations, but really the global state.

Comment: The question: Should I be concerned about the global state? Currently, I only want the Fortran code to be site-effect free. I do not understand, why I should be concerned about the global state which should be handled by OpenMP itself. Does it really matter for me?

Comment: @Rick: I think the subtlety is that the `pure` attribute does not MAKE the procedure free of side-effects, it only signals the compiler that it is, and in a rather strict way: functions may only have `intent(in)` arguments and subroutines may only modify their own `intent([in]out)` arguments. No other effects on the state of the program are allowed. OpenMP does have such effects, but that is not to say they are unwanted. You just have to verify for yourself that your algorithm is thread-safe, or parallelise with native Fortran (2008) coarrays.

Comment: Yes, I exactly think that way, too. But why is in the OpenMP standard written (twice!): "OpenMP directives may not appear in PURE or ELEMENTAL procedures." With your arguments, a short warning would be enough that OpenMP breaks pure, but does not have any other effects to the Fortran code itself. The question: Is it really so? Or is there more behind all this? I am still confused and I also did not get a concrete answer on OpenMP.org forum.

Comment: @Rick: Well, in a literal sense, OpenMP does not have effects on "the Fortran code itself", i.e. the code you write down, but it does affect the compiled code in a way that violates the requirements for `pure`. Namely by modifying some variables, perhaps completely hidden from the user, but still outside the scope of the procedure. Even if your code would produce identical results without parallel execution. Or at least, that's why I think this is in the OpenMP standard; of course the writers of the standard should know it exactly.

Comment: @Rick I look there and I think

Comment: @VladimirF That was (poor?) attempt at providing a guess at one technical reason for the previous comment by the OP - otherwise I think your answer is more than sufficient.  Subject to a program meeting certain restrictions/floating point vagaries aside, the base language is deterministic.  The rules for FORALL, DO CONCURRENT and specification expressions are such that the determinism exists regardless of any reordering of execution (including execution in parallel) in those language elements.  If OpenMP directives were allowed in PURE procedures, that determinism goes out the window.

Comment: ifort 14.0.2 allows compiling pure subroutines with OpenMP directives inside.